# Magento, Query to associate some products from one category to another category

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I have a multistore magento installation
In one store we have a category tree like this
-Printer
-Toner
-Etc

In the second one we have
-Printer
-Supplies
   - Toner

I need to build a query to associate the products from the first toner category, to the second toner category.  The problem is that some of them are already associated in the second category.

I cant do this with magento easily, so I suppose it needs to be done with mysql

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I need to build a query to associate the products". What is it you are trying to do with this relation?

Comment: I need to associate the products with the new category. I need that the products appear in the other store as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using mysql, but I found a tool called Magento Store Desktop Manager which does massive category association.